Trace over fermion propagator in the presence of an external gauge field $A$
Is there any general technique of solving traces like:
\begin{equation}
\operatorname{Tr}\left(\gamma^\mu \frac{1}{\hat{p} + e \hat{A} - m}\right)
\end{equation}
except expansion in series:
$$\gamma^\mu \frac{1}{\hat{p} + e \hat{A} - m} = \gamma^\mu \frac{1}{\hat{p} - m}  + \gamma^\mu \frac{1}{\hat{p} - m}e \hat{A}\frac{1}{\hat{p} - m} + ...$$.
For free propagators the formula of difference of squares is applied, but in this case it does not work because
$$
\operatorname{Tr}\left(\gamma^\mu \frac{\hat{p}+e\hat{A} + m}{(\hat{p}+e\hat{A})^2 - m^2} \right) 
$$
the term $(\hat{p}+e\hat{A})^2$ is non-trivial. Introducing the following notation $\hat{P}=\hat{p}+e \hat{A}$ we can illustrate
$$
\begin{aligned}
\hat{P} \hat{P}=P_\mu P_\nu \gamma^\mu \gamma^\nu=P_\mu P_\nu[ & \left.\frac{1}{2}\left(\gamma^\mu \gamma^\nu+\gamma^\nu \gamma^\mu\right)+\frac{1}{2}\left(\gamma^\mu \gamma^\nu-\gamma^\nu \gamma^\mu\right)\right]= \\
& =P_\mu P^\mu-i P_\mu P_\nu \sigma^{\mu \nu}=P_\mu P^\mu-i \frac{1}{2}\left[P_\mu, P_\nu\right] \sigma^{\mu \nu}
\end{aligned}
$$
where $\sigma^{\mu \nu}=\frac{i}{2}\left[\gamma^\mu, \gamma^\nu\right]$
. Thus
$$
\begin{aligned}
-i \frac{1}{2}\left[P_\mu, P_\nu\right] \sigma^{\mu \nu}=i \frac{1}{2}\left[\partial_\mu-i e A_\mu, \partial_\nu\right. & \left.-i e A_\nu\right] \sigma^{\mu \nu}= \\
& =\frac{1}{2} e\left(\partial_\mu A_\nu-\partial_\nu A_\mu\right) \sigma^{\mu \nu}=e \frac{1}{2} F_{\mu \nu} \sigma^{\mu \nu}
\end{aligned}
$$
which means that
$$
(\hat{p}+e\hat{A})^2 = (p+eA)^2+\frac{1}{2} e F_{\mu \nu} \sigma^{\mu \nu}.
$$
and that the denominator will not come out from the trace.
Are there any general methods for calculating traces of terms with non-trivial denominators?

You can try to use the https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/eta+invariant régularisation, but it is a bit overkill. If I remember correctly, Peskin and Schroeder have a couple of pages about your problem.

How about expanding the square in the denominator, and then using expansion in series?
